# Rgex doen't work with sed command as expected

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I have a text file containing :

> A 25 27 50
>
> B 35 75
>
> C 75 78
>
> D 99 88 76

I wanted to delete the line that does not have the fourth field(the fourth pair of digits).
Expected output :

> A 25 27 50
>
> D 99 88 76

I know that **awk** command would be the best option for such task, but i'm wondering what's the problem with my **sed** command since it should work as you can see below :

```
sed -E '/^[ABCD] ([0-9][0-9]) \1$/d' text.txt
```

Using POSIX ERE with back-referencing (\1) to refer to the previous pattern surrounded with parenthesis.

I have tried this command instead :

```
sed -E '/^[ABCD] ([0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9]$/d' text.txt
```

But it seems to delete only the first occurrence of what i want.
I would appreciate further explanation of,

- why the back-referencing doesn't work as expected.
- what's the matter with the first occurrence in the second attempt,should i included global option if yes then how, since i already tried adding it at the end along side with **/d** (for delete) but it didn't work .

Answer (score 4):

Much much easier with `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NF == 4' file

A 25 27 50
D 99 88 76
```

This `awk` command uses default field separator of space or tab and checks a condition `NF == 4` to make sure we print lines with 4 fields only.

---

With `sed` it would be (assuming no leading+trailing spaces in each line):

```sh
sed -nE '/^[^[:blank:]]+([[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+){3}$/p' file

A 25 27 50
D 99 88 76
```

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog: Did this work out?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples in `sed` program you could try following. Written and tested in GNU `sed`.

```
sed -nE '/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}[^[:space:]]+$/p' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply stopping the printing for lines by `sed`'s `-n` option. Then using `-E` for using ERE in program. In main program using regex to match from starting non-space(1 or more occurrences) followed by spaces(1 or more occurrences) and this combo 3 times(to match 3 fields basically) which is followed by non spaces 1 or more occurrences till end of line's value, if this regex matched then print that line.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/\S+/&/4p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` and on extended regexp `-E`.

Substitute the 4th field with itself and print the result.